# Simplifying configurable products with multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I'm currently setting up an online shop whose main products are lamps.

Lamps are available in different colors/materials. So basically I have a configurable product with several simple products associated for each color/material.

Also, if you buy a lamp, you'll get 2 illuminants for free. There are 4 (or even more) light color types available. These illuminants don't affect the price and are always in stock.

Now, if I would create simple products for each color/illuminant combination, this would be an administrative disaster. I would end up with about 100 simple products for a single configurable product.

My question is, how is it possible to setup the light color attribute dropdown in the product view without actually being associated to a simple product?

Comment: you can try custom options. please tell me if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to create Attribute and associate simple Product then you can create **Custom Options** for that particular product it provide same dropdown at frontend.

Follow below url for tutorial

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-product-custom-options.html#gref

Comment: Thank you @murtuza. This is a much better approach. I'll wait a view hours if someone has a more central (global) solution, otherwise I'll accept your answer!